# Getting result in dropdownlist using ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax

I wish to get result of semester in dropdown list from db, while selecting course from previous dropdown list. I'm begginer in php. Below is the code I tried.

**AJAX CODE**:

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

document.getElementById("txtHint").value=xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser1.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<tr class="light">
          <th height="43">COURSE</th>
            <td><select name="course" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a course</option>
  <option value="UG">UG</option>
  <option value="PG">PG</option>

  </select></td>

          </tr>
          <tr class="dark">
            <th height="43">SEMESTER</th>
            <td>

            <select name="sem" id="txtHint">

            </select>

              </td>
```

**GETUSER1.php**:

```
<?php
$q =$_GET['q'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("internal");

$sql="SELECT * FROM tblcourse WHERE course = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo  "<option>".$row['sem']."</option>";


}

?>
```

Comment: are the html page and the php script (`getuser1.php`) within the same directory?

Comment: incidentally  the `mysql` api has been deprecated so depending upon your version of PHP you may not have the `mysql_connect`, `mysql_select_db` or `mysql_query` etc functions available. Check your console for errors/.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. [Here is a good](http://wiki.hashphp.org/Validation) resource on how to fix that type of issue.

Comment: Try innerHTML instead of value too.
document.getElementById("txtHint").value should be document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML

Comment: Thanku..i tried innerHTML too. All are in same directory

Comment: Using innerHTML, the code is working and answer is getting in div.The issue is ,i wish to get the answer in a dropdownlist.IS this possible?